# Cordova VideoPlay from assets

Tags: android, cordova

Line 82-99
https://github.com/raulduran/VideoPlayer/blob/master/src/android/VideoPlayer.java

I am trying to use the above cordova plugin to play video from asset folder. However at line 91, there is a copy function which I cannot understand. Also, the video size is over 200MB, so copy takes a good amount of time for copying.

Can the video be played directly from initial filepath?